# White, filling type of, tooth medication. What is it?

Tags: dentistry, tooth-decay, mouth

The tooth was drilled deeply to the nerves and before the end of the visit, it was filled with so called medication. Its color is 100% white and it's very easily dissolvable.

Question is what is it exactly? Does it have healing properties? Is it a pain killer? Does it threaten the nerves in any way?

Comment: It sounds like a root canal. If that's what it was, the nerve was intentionally destroyed during the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify : did the doctor touch the nerve or not?

- If he did he probably placed calcium hydroxide inside the nerve space and removed the nerve. you will need a future appointment to complete the root canal therapy.
- If he did not, he has placed a sedative dressing (temporary filling) made of **clove oil extract and zinc oxide** (**Zonalin** is the name of this product) which is antibacterial and sedative for the pulp (the nerve). The doctor will eventually do a permanent filling or a root canal, depending on how your tooth reacts. A stronger and longer lasting version of this product exists, Under the brand name IRM. This formulation contains more resin, which give the product additional strength, but makes it harder to manipulate.

If you want more info on the product, read about it on Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_oxide_eugenol 
Or in Dentistry textbooks such as *Materials in Dentistry: Principles and Applications*, 2001, 2d Edition, Lippincott Williams & Wilkin